# Python 3.5 Lotto program help (simple)

Tags: python, random

Hi this is my following python 3.5 lotto program

```
import random
one = (random.randint(1,40))
two = (random.randint(1,40))
three = (random.randint(1,40))
four = (random.randint(1,40))
five = (random.randint(1,40))
six = (random.randint(1,40))
seven = (random.randint(1,40))
#But it's going to print duplicate numbers. How to fix?

print ("The winning lotto numbers this week are:", one, two, three, four, five, six,"and", seven,)

print (input("Press the enter key to exit"))
```

How do I prevent the program from printing duplicate numbers in the results?

Thank you

Comment: Did any of the answers help? If so, please upvote & mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) method instead, to create a list like this:

```
winners = random.sample(range(1,41), 7)
print ("The winning lotto numbers this week are: {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, and {}".format(*winners))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use random.sample

```
import random

numbers = range(1, 41)
draw = random.sample(numbers, 7)
```